# How to flatten 2 tier lists of objects and summing properties where other properties are common

Tags: c#, linq, list, object

I realise the name of this question is confusing, so let me rather explain my scenario.

I have a list of objects. This list has an entry for each user. Each user then has a list of categories, and each category has a category id, and some values that have already been calculated. I need to flatten my objects in a list of categories, where the properties of each category has been summed. Each user will have the same amount of categories in their lists, and each category will be present in each user's lists (in other words, each user will have the same list of categories, the calculated properties will only be different).

My classes are:

```cs
public class category {
     public int categoryID { get; set; }
     public decimal categoryValue { get; set; }
     public decimal categoryValue2 { get; set; }
}

public class user {
    public List<category> categories { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to achieve is by using Linq (or whatever means will be most efficient) to flatten the data to a single List where the categories are still split up by their respective ID's but categoryValue and categoryValue2 have been totaled respectively. Hence I get a 2 totaled value per category for all users.

I have tried doing a for loop as follows:

```cs
List<category> categoryTotals = new List<category> {};
foreach (category loopCategory in users[0].categories) {
    category currentCategory = new category();
    category = users.Select(x => x.categories).Where(y=>y.categoryID== loopCategory.categoryID)).Select(t => new {t....
}
```

But the t is giving me linq functions, not the properties that I want to sum.

I have also tried a similar approach using just linq, but after doing the SelectMany, followed by the GroupBy, the succeeding select statement again doesn't expose the category lists's properties.

Many thanks!

Comment: `users.SelectMany(u => u.categories)` will give you a single flat sequence of all the categories for all the users.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Noted. However, I then need to group this flat sequence of categories by their ID's and calculate the values of each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ `SelectMany` method combined woth `GroupBy`

```
var sumList = users
    .SelectMany(u => u.categories)
    .GroupBy(c => c.categoryID)
    .Select(g => new category()
    {
       categoryID = g.Key,
       categoryValue = g.Sum(z => z.categoryValue),
       categoryValue2 = g.Sum(z => z.categoryValue2),
    })
   .ToList();
```

This will return `List<category>` with `categoryValue` and `categoryValue2` summed for all users.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Quite simple when seeing it, however after several hours of toiling with this (I'm fairly new to Linq) I seemed impossible. I got stuck on why the Group By was giving me an enumerable without the id, not knowing the Key was what was needed. I further adapted this (I could unfortunately not post the actual code) to group by a complex key so I could get the category name (not included in question) and the category order.

Comment: @EugenedeLange Yeah, it seem tricky to use the return type of GroupBy this `IGroupping<T>` interface but if you know how to do it it's a cinch.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
var groupSums = 
    from g in users.SelectMany(u => u.categories).GroupBy(c => c.categoryID)
    select new
    {
        categoryID = g.Key,
        CategoryValueSum = g.Sum(c => c.categoryValue),
        CategoryValue2Sum = g.Sum(c => c.categoryValue2),
    };
```

`users.SelectMany(u => u.categories).GroupBy(c => c.categoryID)` gives you a sequence of `Group<category>` objects. Each has a `Key` property equal to the `categoryID` for the group, and also implements `IEnumerable<category>`.

The whole thing gives you a flat sequence of anonymous objects with a `categoryID` property, and two sum properties for the sums of the two category values. Anonymous classes can be limiting, so depending on what you're doing with the results, you may want to write a new quickie class for that.

And of course if you need to keep the results around for some reason, call `ToList()` on the results.

Answer (score 0):

tested it out and it looks like this. You will get  grouped category list with your desired aggregated result.

```
    var cats = users.SelectMany(x => x.categories).GroupBy(x => x.CategoryID)
        .Select(x => new Category()
        {
            CategoryID = x.Key,
            CategoryValue = x.Sum(y => y.CategoryValue),
            CategoryValue2 = x.Sum(y => y.CategoryValue2)
        });
```